# Terraform plan claims to delete and recreate Elastic Beanstalk environment variables unnecessarily

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform-provider-aws

When creating/applying a Terraform plan for an Elastic Beanstalk environment, I am always shown this (e.g.):

```
- setting {
    - name      = "TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID" -> null
    - namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment" -> null
    - value     = "AC2e9cb3789c4ec87ac9XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" -> null
  }
+ setting {
    + name      = "TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"
    + namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    + value     = "AC2e9cb3789c4ec87ac9XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  }
```

The value of the `TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID` env var is identical before and after the plan is applied.

Why is Terraform removing and re-adding my env vars?

My environment config is of the form:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "backend" {
  name                   = "${var.eb_application_name}-${var.env}"
  application            = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.backend.name
  solution_stack_name    = "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.5.1 running Docker"
  wait_for_ready_timeout = "30m"

  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = local.all_settings
    content {
      namespace = setting.value["namespace"]
      name      = setting.value["name"]
      value     = setting.value["value"]
    }
  }
}

locals {
  all_settings = concat(local.load_balancer_settings, local.spring_boot_environment_variable_settings)

  load_balancer_settings = [
    {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment"
      name      = "LoadBalancerType"
      value     = var.loadbalancer_type
    }
  ]

  spring_boot_environment_variable_settings = [

    {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
      name      = "TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"
      value     = var.twilio_account_sid
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Without the config we have to speculate. Is this a dynamic block based on unordered elements?

Comment: So this confirms my theory that is potentially occurring due to the state file relying on ordering for idempotence determination.

Comment: @MattSchuchard "ordering for idempotence determination" - could you please clarify what do you mean by that? Never heard about this in TF.

Comment: I can confirm that it is not due to having dynamic settings (I have reverted to static settings).

I am seeing `Note: Objects have changed outside of Terraform` during each `plan`/`apply`.